# Vue - updating child components without updating parent components. Best approach?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, parent-child

I'm new to Vue and I'm trying to dynamically create a list of Divs, each with X number of child Divs. Also children will be added, edited or deleted at various points.

The data of the divs initially arrive through a structured array called `pageObjects`:

```js
var pageObjects = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Page 1",
    subpages: [
      {
        id: "2_1",
        title: "Page 2 Subpage 1"
      },
      {
        id: "2_2",
        title: "Page 2 Subpage 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Page 2",
    subpages: [
      {
        id: "2_1",
        title: "Page 2 Subpage 1"
      },
      {
        id: "2_2",
        title: "Page 2 Subpage 2"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I can create the parent and child divs easily using custom Vue components:

```js
//init the container
var pagescontainer = new Vue({
  el: '#pagescontainer',
  data: {
    pageObjects
  }
});

Vue.component('page-component', {
  template: `
    <div v-bind:id="'page' + page.id">
      This is a parent div with title {{page.title}} 
      <subpage-component v-for="subpage in page.subpages" v-bind:subpage="subpage" />
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    page: Object
  }
});

Vue.component('subpage-component', {
  template: `
    <div v-bind:id="'subpage' + subpage.id">
      This is a sub page with title {{ subpage.title }}
    </div>`,
  props: {
    subpage: Object
  }
});
```

All parents and children can then be created via HTML:

```html
<div id="pagescontainer">
  <page-component v-for="page in pageObjects" :page="page"/>
</div>
```

This works - but I don't know the best practices for editing the child data, or adding new children dynamically. I can change the `pageObject` array, which updates all the current content, but there must be a better way - editing the entire array for all parents and divs just to change one part of one child div seems excessive and inefficient. Plus I can't add/delete children just by removing it from the array.

To independently edit the content of a child div I tried adding "data" variables and methods directly to the subpage component:

```js
Vue.component('subpage-component', {
  template: `
    <div v-bind:id="'subpage' + subpage.id">
      This is a sub page with title {{ subpage.title }}
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    subpage: Object
  },
  data: {
    title: "some title here"
  },
  methods: {
    updateSubPageHtml: function (_title) {
      console.log(this);
      console.log("updating title to " + _title);
      this.title = _title;
    }
  }
});
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: title is not defined.

Can anybody suggest a better way to add/edit/delete children to the parents dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `data` should always be a function, which returns an object and not just an object.

You can normally just replace the whole pageObjects array. Vue will still compare the resulting html with the virtual DOM and only change the things actually needed. Also you could change pages and sub-pages directly using the IDs you gave them. Doing this globally you can use `$emit` and change state in parent component or integrate Vuex into your project.

Vue will not re-render the components, which have the same prop values, after editing the array.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to look in to Vuex